# what line would I use to cancel a dialogue page

Tags: android, alert

I've made an alert dialogue page and I want to have the button on my dialogue page return me to the main activity it came from

but apparently the line I have cancels the entire app instead

what line would I need to do this? thanks

```
Button Yes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yesbutton);
Yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `finish();`

The default implementation of any button as described below will just cancel the dialog,

A much cleaner way to create an alertDialog is :

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(activity.this)
                        .setTitle("MY alert")
                        .setMessage("my message")
                        .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        }).show();
```